# Colab unexpectedly gets stuck and hangs after executing input() function

Tags: google-colaboratory, user-input

Colab unexpectedly gets stuck and hangs after executing input() function (Python), e.g.: input("What is your name? "). see attached file. I am using Colab free version.
Please advice, what can be done? Thanks in advance!

After Google Colab gets stuck and hangs the only thing to do is to interrupt execution and re-run the cell

Comment: What if you just type something like : print(1+1) Does it work? By the way, I don't see any attachment.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response. print (1+1) works fine. Colab gets stack only after executing the input. BTW, it happens to many of my students.

Comment: Let's say you create a new notebook on google colab with just a single statement which is: print(1+1) Do you get an answer?

Comment: Yes, I get a quick answer for the "print (1+1) statement

Comment: I have no idea how new you are to google colab, so I'm sorry if my questions look stupid... But, If you have a statement in a cell like: Answer=input('Give an answer:') Then you should SHIFT+ENTER on the cell to run it, then give the answer and then hit ENTER again. Do we agree?

Comment: It could also be a problematic browser extension/addon. You could then try to disable all of them and see if it then works. Afterwhat you re-enable them one by one to see which one is the cause of the problem. In my case, I use an adblocker, a cookieblocker, a privacy badger and so on and I don't have that problem.

Comment: The problem occurs only with input, occurs on different computers, and is not consistent: Sometimes it works fine and sometimes the Colab gets stuck.

Comment: BTW, after I interrupt the execution and re-run the cell the input works fine

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is for you to check the stability of your internet connection. But that's probably not the problem... Sorry I can't help.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. As this problem occurs to many of my students, who use different computers from different locations, and occurs only with the input function ... I am not sure it is the stability of the internet connection :(